# Fetching data everytime user is typing

Tags: reactjs, axios, fetch-api

I am trying to fetch data from GitHub API, so basically I want to fetch the actual data when the user click on submit button.
But it fetches the data as the user types.

```
const [inputText, setInputText] = useState('');
  const [data, setData] = useState({ data: [] });

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`https://api.github.com/users/${inputText}/repos`)
      .then((response) => {
        setData(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('error', error);
      });
  }, [inputText]);

  const handleSubmit = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(data);
  };

  const inputHandler = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setInputText(e.target.value);
  };
```

and here is my JSX:

```
return (
    <>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/history">History</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <h3>GitHub API</h3>
      <TextField
        onChange={inputHandler}
        variant="outlined"
        label="Search for a user"
      />
      <Button variant="contained" onClick={handleSubmit}>
        Submit
      </Button>
    </>
  );
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `useEffect` has a dependency with `inputText` which means any time that value changes the action wrapped in `useEffect` is called. From what you provided, you can simply move the functionality from the `useEffect` into `handleSubmit`:

```
  const handleSubmit = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
    axios
      .get(`https://api.github.com/users/${inputText}/repos`)
      .then((response) => {
        setData(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('error', error);
      })
  };
```

Comment: I've tried that before, but the thing is that in fetches the data on second click and not on the first one.

Comment: Is that behavior consistent on all browsers? Was it with or without preventDefault?